# I test a website in react and my functions are not showing when I run my code

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-native, react-dom

`

```
function bannner() {
    const title = "c'est pur "
      return (<h1>{title}</h1>)
    }

function cart() {
    const prixbedo = 10
    const prixhero = 20
    const prixcoc = 70
    return (<div>
            <h2>Panier</h2>
            <ul>
            <li>bedo : {prixbedo}$</li>
            <li>heroïne : {pixhero}$</li>
            <li>cocaïne : {prixcoc}$</li>
            </ul>
        </div>)
}

ReactDOM.render(<div><banner /><cart /></div>, document.getElementById("root"))
```

i declared my file .js in my file .html when I test with simple function is good I see on my website the result but with this code nothing happens

Comment: React 18 [has a different render method](https://reactjs.org/blog/2022/03/08/react-18-upgrade-guide.html). Also both of your components should be in PascalCase: so `Cart` and `Banner`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not write the name of the tale in lowercase.
Causes an error in the function rendering.

Write as follows:

```js
function Banner() {
  const title = "c'est pur "
  return <h1>{title}</h1>
}

function Cart() {
  const prixbedo = 10
  const prixhero = 20
  const prixcoc = 70
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Panier</h2>
      <ul>
        <li>bedo : {prixbedo}$</li>
        <li>heroïne : {prixhero}$</li>
        <li>cocaïne : {prixcoc}$</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <div>
    <Banner />
    <Cart />
  </div>,
  document.getElementById("root")
)
```

Comment: "function poison"?

Comment: yes I change only for test but it's the same in lowercase or uppercase my website its a white pages

Comment: white page?
Do you have any errors in the log console?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create root.

```
function bannner() {
    const title = "c'est pur "
      return (<h1>{title}</h1>)
    }

function cart() {
    const prixbedo = 10
    const prixhero = 20
    const prixcoc = 70
    return (<div>
            <h2>Panier</h2>
            <ul>
            <li>bedo : {prixbedo}$</li>
            <li>heroïne : {pixhero}$</li>
            <li>cocaïne : {prixcoc}$</li>
            </ul>
        </div>)
}

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot( document.getElementById("root"))
root.render(<div><banner /><cart /></div>)
```

Comment: I want to add to @Roman Nichi answer that you need to Capitalize your function declaration names since its the way to let React now that your functions are not just functions, but React Components.
``` 
function Bannner(){...} 
function Cart(){...} 

in JSX: <Banner /> 
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your component not showing up is because you used lower case to write your functions just like other people have pointed out. I just wanted to give more context.

According to the react docs [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#html-tags-vs.-react-components), in JSX, lower-case tag names are considered to be HTML tags. eg

`<cart />` compiles to React.createElement('cart') (html tag).

`<Cart />` compiles to React.createElement(Cart) (a react component)

So because `<cart />` is not a recognised tag, it doesn't show. Hope this helps

Comment: finally the problem does not come from the code I tested it on codepen and it shows the good result but on my computer when I launch it they do not work